# PYTHON INICIANTE Porque está dando o erro 'is not defined' , como eu conserto isso?

Tags: python

Olá , sou iniciante, preciso de ajuda.
Eu defini as populações das regiões:

populacao_Nordeste = 27.09
populacao_Sul = 14.26
populacao_Sudeste = 42.04
populacao_Norte = 8.82
populacao_CentroOeste = 7.79

E eu usei um input , regiao = input("Digite a região:").

Entao porque quando eu escrevo populacao_regiao aparece que nao esta definido. Por exemplo se eu digitasse "Sul" no input, a populacao_regiao teria que ser 14.26 não é? Vou deixar uma imagem para facilitar.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: "*Vou deixar uma imagem para facilitar*" - na verdade a imagem dificulta as coisas. O ideal é sempre colocar o código como **texto**, entenda os motivos [lendo o **FAQ**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/112052).

Comment: Você não criou nenhuma variável chamada populacao_regiao.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não criou nenhuma variável chamada populacao_regiao. Alem disso o tipo da sua variável regiao é do tipo str, antes de fazer a operação de divisão faça um teste condicional para que possa usar suas variáveis criadas. Ou use dicionários.
Eu sugiro:

```
regiao = input('regiao: ')

regioes = {'norte':12.1, 'sul':14.7, 'nordeste':18.6, 'suldeste':21.8}
populacao_regiao = {'norte':25.4, 'sul':27.8, 'nordeste':29.1, 'suldeste':31.2}

regiao_populacao = populacao_regiao[regiao]
regiao = regioes[regiao]

w = regiao/regiao_populacao
""" ...Resto do seu codigo..."""
```

Answer (score 1):

Ai no seu caso, vc não iniciou a variável `popolucao_regiao` em nenhum lugar. Vc vai ter que fazer uma verificação pelo valor q o usuário digitou. Por exemplo:

```
if regiao == 'sul':
   # aqui você pega o valor da região e divide pelo valor da populacao daquela região
   w = 15.2 / 14.26
elif regiao == 'nordeste':
   w = 21.5 / 27.09
```

Na forma que você fez ai, o python não consegue identificar qual região ele deve usar para fazer o calculo

Answer (score 1):

É que na verdade você não pode acessar as variáveis "Norte", "Sul" ... dessa forma.

o calculo que você está tentando fazer pega o valor de seu input que é uma str e tenta dividir uma variável que não existe "populacao_regiao".

Uma forma de fazer esse calculo seria usando dicionários:

```
regioes = {} 
regioes['Nordeste'] = 21.5
regioes['Sul'] = 15.2
regioes['Sudeste'] = 42.04
regioes['Norte'] = 8.82
regioes['Centro Oeste'] = 7.79

populacoes = {}
populacoes['Nordeste'] = 21.5
populacoes['Sul'] = 15.2
populacoes['Sudeste'] = 46.2
populacoes['Norte'] = 8.6
populacoes['Centro Oeste'] = 8.5


index = input("Digite qual região quer avaliar: Norte, Nordeste, Sul, Sudeste, Centro Oeste ")

w = regioes[index] / populacoes[index]

if w > 1:
  print(f'A região {index} está bem representada no ProUni')
else:
  print(f'A região {index} está bem representada no ProUni')
```